# Indefinite leave to remain

Tags: united-kingdom

My son is British married to a Japanese girl who has ILR. He is working in NZ at the moment on contract and will be returning with her to the UK before the 2 years are up.

The question is: Can they come back for a couple of weeks and then go back to NZ for another contract, and could they do that for a while or would the ILR be taken away?

Comment: Just to clarify, the ILR is for the UK, or NZ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the answer to Mark Mayo's question is that she has ILR in the UK, then in general the answer to your question is no. If the immigration officer sees how long she has been gone and realizes that she is just going back to New Zealand in a couple of weeks, it is obvious that she is not a resident in the UK much less a permanent resident. If the ILR isn't cancelled right then, it would become invalid after two years anyway. They are getting a lot more strict about this and the UK has recently introduced exit checks. It is now effectively impossible to try the brief-visit-to-maintain-ILR scheme anymore.